# Series of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jstl

I'm trying to figure out a better way to structure some of my code so that I don't have a ton of conditionals here. I have a series of checkboxes that someone authors on the backend and if they are checked I set a variable with a specific value. I then use that variable and set options in my jQuery plugin. This works just fine but there's got to be a better way as oppose to having all these conditionals. Is there someway I could create a loop or something similar?

```
<c:if test="${prop.article}">
  <c:set var="contentArticle" value="blog"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${prop.quote}">
  <c:set var="contentQuote" value="cited"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${prop.music}">
  <c:set var="contentMusic" value="itunes"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${prop.money}">
  <c:set var="contentMoney" value="money"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${prop.check}">
  <c:set var="contentCheck" value="check"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${prop.charge}">
  <c:set var="contentCharge" value="visa"/>
</c:if>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.gallery').sourcesPlugin({
        media: '${contentArticle},${contentQuote},${contentMusic}',
        payment: '${contentMoney},${contentCheck},${contentCharge}',
    });
});
</script>
```